# Prime Numbers, Sieve of Erasthosthenes , Python

Tags: python-3.x, iteration

I am working on a program that prints in a range,  the list of a possible prime numbers when the user inputs the highest integer.  Basically the sieve of Erasthothenes.

Now,  this  block of code is supposed to iterate for all of the values of consecInt(a variable that stores a list of 2 to that highest integer) and remove their multiples.  But for some reason i dont quite understand,  it only works for the first value.

```
print("                 Sieve of Erasthothenes\n    Program that generates the possible prime numbers within a given range")

n = int(input("\nEnter the highest range:   "))

def primeList(n):

    j = 2
   consecInt = [int(i) for i in range(2, n+1)]

#A = [i != False for i in range(2, n+1)]

    for i in consecInt:
        p = i
        while j <= n:
            c = j*p
            if c <= n:
                consecInt.remove(c)
             j+=1

    print(consecInt)

primeList(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be resetting `j` to `2` at every iteration of the *`for`* loop. Other than that, there are a couple other errors.

```
def primeList(n):
    consecInt = [int(i) for i in range(2, n+1)]

    for i in consecInt:
        j = 2      ## reset `j` to 2 at every iteration
        while j*i <= n:   ## it is sufficient to check `j*i <= n` rather than `j <= n`
            c = j*i

            if c in consecInt:    ## if `c` is NOT in consecInt, a ValueError will be raised
                consecInt.remove(c)

            j += 1

    print(consecInt)

primeList(n)
```

Comment: @Chi if you've found this answer helpful, please consider marking this as the accepted answer.

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer. There'll be a checkmark next to my answer. If you think my answer _deserves_ to be accepted, do accept it.